# why is XMLHttpRequest response returning null if request fails?

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to handle different response codes from XMLHttpRequest. However, if I get anything other than 200, the response object is always null and does not print the expected status (e.g 403, 404 etc.) . Here's my code:

```
 var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
 xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4)
    {
        if (xhttp.status == 200) {
           console.log(xhttp.status);
        }else{
            console.log(xhttp.status);

        }
    }
};

xhttp.open('GET', url, true);
xhttp.send();
```

Console output when it works:

```
200
```

Console output when it fails for any reason:

```
0
```

As an example, for error code 400, console will display the following:

> script.js:11
>   2script.js:55 GET
>   https://api.nytimes.com/svc/search/v2/articlesearch.json?api-key=eaf6455bd8eb4f11a1f08923b811081e&q=1%&%%&begin_date=1234&end_date=123 400 (nginx/1.10.2)
>  searchQuery @ script.js:55
>  reader.onload @
>   script.js:14
>  index.html:1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   https://api.nytimes.com/svc/search/v2/articlesearch.json?api-key=eaf6455bd8eb4f11a1f08923b811081e&q=1%&%%&begin_date=1234&end_date=123.
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. The response
>   had HTTP status code 400.

I would prefer to do this in pure Javascript so please don't suggest jquery

Comment: CORS problem will result in status of 0 - nothing to do with the status being other than 200. i.e. non CORS error with response status non 200 and a response body won't have a `null` response

Comment: hmm, though, nytimes api DOES return CORS headers - the fact that you are getting a CORS error means the problem is probably with the  `Origin 'null'` ... oh, I see, with a bad request, that API does NOT return CORS headers, only with a good request ... poor API design really

Comment: I'm a bit inexperienced with AJAX and only just read a bit about CORS today. If origin 'null' is the issue, any way of getting around that?

Comment: no, that isn't the issue ... the issue is that the API doesn't return cors headers for a bad request, so you can't access the response .... as I said, poorly designed API by code monkeys that don't understand how to create a workable API - nothing you can do about it

Comment: Oh :( Thanks for your help @JaromandaX

Answer (score 1):

if the only purpose is to handle different error codes, you can try

```
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onload = function() {

        if (xhttp.status == 200) {
           console.log(xhttp.status);
        }else{
            console.log(xhttp.status);
        }

    };

    xhttp.open('GET', url, true);
    xhttp.send();
```

Comment: That works. Thanks! Out of curiosity why didn't this work for onreadystatechange ?

Comment: Actually it's still failing.. try this link: https://api.nytimes.com/svc/search/v2/articlesearch.json?api-key=eaf6455bd8eb4f11a1f08923b811081e&q=this&begin_date=won%27t&end_date=work